# Vue.js: field values go back as soon as they lose focus

Tags: vue.js, crud, quasar-framework

I'm experimenting with a very simple CRUD application. However any values entered in the filter fields or in the edit dialog go back to the defaults as soon as the field loses focus. Here's a snippet:

```html
<q-input v-for="field in fields" :value="input[field.name]"/></q-input>
```

I'm quite new to Vue, but I believe this should be simple for an experienced user, but I didn't find any answers in StackOverflow or elsewhere. Check it out:

https://codepen.io/rubem-pechansky/pen/PvjZMb

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `v-model`

```
<q-input v-for="field in fields" v-model="input[field.name]"/></q-input>
```

`:value` only set data to the input, but it doesn't get updated data back.

Comment: Thanks, this certainly helped me. There are still a couple of strange things going on in this pen, though. The filter values are still stuck to the defaults and values are updated instantaneously in the list, which is not what I want from a dialog box. In my production code things are a bit different, so I'll have to compare both and see what's going on. I'll come back later. Thanks again!